# How can I add header to colorbar legend in xyplot (lattice package)?

Tags: r, lattice

I am reproducing figure 5.6 in Lattice book by Deepayan Sarkar, although using one single panel. At the moment, I am struggling to get a header on top of the colorbar...

Here is some reproducible code.

```
x <- seq(1,20,.1)
y <- rnorm(length(x))
z <- seq(1,200,length.out=length(x))

cols <- rainbow(100)[cut(z,100,label=F)]

xyplot(y~x, aspect="iso", type=c("p","g"), col=1, pch=21,fill=cols,
   legend=list(right=
       list(fun = draw.colorkey,
            args=list(key=list(col = rainbow,at = do.breaks(range(z),100))))),
panel=function(x,y,...){
panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
}
)
```

Any clue? Thanks,

A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `draw.colorkey` does not respect the `title=` property of the `key=` list for some reason. But you can specify your own grob. Here we use `packGrob` (from `grid`) to modify the standard `colorkey` grob. Try this

```
library(grid)
my.legend <- packGrob(
    draw.colorkey(key=list(col = rainbow, at = do.breaks(range(z),100))), 
    textGrob("My title", x = 0, y = 0.5, just = c("left", "centre")), 
    height=unit(2, "lines"),side="top", dynamic=T)

xyplot(y~x, aspect="iso", type=c("p","g"), col=1, pch=21,fill=cols,
    legend=list(right=list(fun=my.legend)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work if `groups` is not null.

Comment: @Sezen This answer was about adding a title to the color bar legend. In my test this part still works with `groups=`, its just that color color is changed by the groups. Typically `groups=` is used to change the color for different groups so i'm not sure how that would be used when explicitly setting a `fill=` color.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes you are right, I was focused on colouring the points by another variable :) at least, for `pch = 21`, `col` might be set by `groups` and `fill` might be set by `z` values. Of course, this won't make a big difference if we have lots of points. No big deal. Thanks again.